# System.out.printf. Cannot resolve symbol 'out'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, system

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to learn Java. All went well until yesterday when the mentioned error happened.
I didn't make any changes. I was looking for the solution in the following ways:

1. reboot the pc
2. restart IntelliJ.

It keeps showing this error:

[image]

Comment: Please post code here as text. In particular, create a [mcve] which duplicates the error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: agree, however that image also shows the presence of a System.java class, so in this instance, a picture did help solve the problem. Regardless, the question should probably be closed though as a typo/trivial error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a class of your own named `System.java` and you are confusing the compiler (and yourself) with this, since the compiler thinks that `out` should be a static field of this class. Rename that class ASAP.